# How an item(object, image, draw object) on Canvas j2me can be deleted after it has been painted, drawed?

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

How an item(object, image, draw object) on Canvas can be deleted(removed, unplaced with its position deletion(removation)) after it has been painted, drawed?

Comment: please show us some code indicating what you have drawn, and *which* object you want deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set color after painting, please try this method in your program:

```
paint(Graphics g){
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);  getBackground();}
```